# Options for replacing RTMP for live streaming

Tags: html, flash, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp

I have a backend streaming video to web browsers using RTMP. On the browsers we use jwplayer. 
As everybody know flash player is going to be deprecated soon.
Im looking for options to modify the backend using another streaming solution.

We have made some test using DASH but it has too much delay for live streamining compared to RTMP.

What are the options for anyone using RTMP ?

Comment: WebRTC is the only thing that can do low latency in browser without plugins